# Python - How to flatten nested list getting unique values

Tags: python, list, unique

this is my function :

```
extract_unique_elements([2,[[2,4,5],"c",[[["c","d"]]]]])
```

which should return: `{2, 4, 5, “c”, “d”}` (in the form of set).

I looked for some answers but they all for 2D lists.
Thank you. 
But now I already have a solution. thank you all for your help.

```
def extract_unique_elements(lst):
    unique = []
    def recursion_occurs_here(element):
        for item in element:
            if isinstance(item, list):
               recursion_occurs_here(item)
            else:
               unique.append(item)
    recursion_occurs_here(lst)
    extracted = set(unique)
    return extracted
```

Comment: So first look for how to flatten an arbitrarily nested list, then convert to a set

Comment: If you can't find a ready-made solution, how about trying to write your own? Please show us your attempt at solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion to flatten your list:

```
def flatten(d):
  return {i for b in [[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else flatten(i) for i in d] for i in b}

print(flatten([2,[[2,4,5],"c",[[["c","d"]]]]]))
```

Output:

```
set(['d', 2, 4, 'c', 5])
```